# The client loads an old version of my web application. How can I prevent this?

Tags: firefox, apache-http-server, cache

I have a single page web-application (HTML and JS only) that clients visit in their web browser.

If I upload a new version of the web application, the client will still load the old version when visiting the website. To really load the new version, the client has to clear the cache (or disable cache). I am using Firefox so I have to open the inspector, and select the "Disable cache" in the network tab (see picture below).

This is annoying. From college I have a vague memory that HTTP has a header that tells the client that "there is a new version of the website". But is this something I have to enable in the web server application (Apache2)?

[image: firefox]

EDIT:

I'm really confused about whether this is a client or server issue. The "cache-control" request header says "max age 0s". The response from the server says that the file is about 5 days oold. Still, firefox uses the cached version??

[image]

Comment: The server doesn't send a "there is a new version", rather it sends a cache-me-for header and a last modified header.  You may be able to get round the limitation by adding a "?" to the end of the url, possibly with some random data after it to make the client believe it's dynamic data and ignore the cache. But you will also want to modify the headers the web server sends.

Comment: https://www.keycdn.com/blog/http-cache-headers is a good source for this, and yes they need to be set up as part of your server setup.

Comment: Thanks, that's a nice writeup. Please see my question edit.

Comment: I think I found the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8315088/prevent-requirejs-from-caching-required-scripts

Comment: Yep, the problem is not apache2 nor firefox. It is RequireJS that is utilizing the cached version of the web application.